# file.exists() comes out false - but the file is there

Tags: r, file

I'm using R on Windows 10, and I'm trying to use a file in my current folder, but the file can not be found.

I tried to reset the folder, but it did not help:

```r
setwd("C:/Users/ronyj/R_projects/itro_to_bioinformatics/tut_3_fasta")

getwd()
#> "C:/Users/ronyj/R_projects/itro_to_bioinformatics/tut_3_fasta"

file.exists("wuhan_covid_genome.fasta")
#> FALSE

file.exists("C:/Users/ronyj/R_projects/itro_to_bioinformatics/tut_3_fasta/wuhan_covid_genome.fasta")
#> FALSE
```

The file is in the folder:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is your file explorer set to show file extensions? Reason I ask: `.fasta` is not a typical extension for text files. But your file explorer recognizes the file as text. My guess is, that you missed the file extension.

Comment: `list.files()` might help here.

Comment: Thank you so much!!
that did help!